# ListView/GridView с кнопками в строках, получить индекс нажатой кнопки - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview

Привет!
Пишу приложение на `WPF`, которое работает с БД с использованием `EF`.
Есть у меня `Page` с `ListView`, в котором я вывожу различные списки - результаты запросов к таблице БД.
Это таблица заявок (здесь чисто контактная информация), в каждой строке `ListView` добавляется кнопка, по нажатию на которую мне необходимо обработать данную заявку (добавить сугубо техническую информацию, храниться она будет в другой таблице БД).
Сделал так:

```
<ListView Name="lvOrders" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="gvOrders">
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="№ п/п" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=OrderId}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Населенный пункт" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Locality}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Район" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=District}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Улица" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Street}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Дом" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=HouseNumber}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Квартира" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ApartmentNumber}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Номер телефона" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PhoneNumber}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Дополнительный телефон" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AdditionalPhone}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Время прибытия" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ArrivalTime}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Дополнительная информация" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AdditionalInfo}"/>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="gvcArrival" Header="Факт прибытия">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Name="btArrival" Content="Открыть" Padding="5" Click="btArrival_Click"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                     </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  </GridViewColumn>
              </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

В коде (в конструкторе) я передаю предикат-запрос и результат запроса потом вывожу в ListView:

```
public Expression<Func<Order, bool>> Predicate
{
    set
    {
        var orders = context.Orders.Where(value).ToList();
        lvOrders.ItemsSource = orders;
    }
}
```

Всё ок, эта часть работает как надо, но теперь в обработчике `btArrival_Click` мне нужно узнать по кнопке из какой строки был клик, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо!
На самом деле всё оказалось гораздо проще:

```
private void btArrival_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Order order = (sender as Button)?.DataContext as Order;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте свойство `Tag`

```
<Button Name="btArrival" 
        Content="Открыть" 
        Padding="5" 
        Click="btArrival_Click" 
        Tag={Binding Path=OrderId}/>
```

А в обработчике просто читаем это свойство:

```
private void btArrival_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var id = (int)(sender as Button).Tag;     
}
```